# Match a string inside a double quote character and get the next 4 characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I got this string that looks like this `\"yearBirthday\":1979`

I having a rough time matching the string and get the value using string match and string indexof in order to get the value "1979"

Anyone have any other idea with this?

This is the sample string that I want to match

```
<script id=hdpApolloPreloadedData type="application/json">
        {"apiCache":"{\"VariantQuery{\\\"zpid\\\":28261252}\":{\"property\":{\"zpid\":28261252,\"streetAddress\":\"3415 Willow Ridge Dr\",\"zipcode\":\"77339\",\"city\":\"Humble\",\"state\":\"TX\",\"latitude\":30.058258,\"longitude\":-95.199617,\"price\":318000,\"dateSold\":1560543353000,\"datePriceChanged\":1584715800000,\"bathrooms\":5,\"bedrooms\":5,\"livingArea\":3777,\"yearBuilt\":1979,\"lotSize\":9539,\"homeType\":\"SINGLE_FAMILY\",\"homeStatus\":\"FOR_SALE\",\"photoCount\":67,\"imageLink\":\"https:\/\/photos.zillowstatic.com\/p_g\/ISzbrso7jduzha1000000000.jpg\",\"daysOnZillow\":247,\"isFeatured\":false,\"shouldHighlight\":false,\"brokerId\":16722,\"contactPhone\":\"\",\"zestimate\":306939,\"rentZestimate\":2500,\"listing_sub_type\":{\"is_FSBA\":true},\"priceReduction\":\"$5,000 (Mar 20)\",\"isUnmappable\":false,\"rentalPetsFlags\":64,\"mediumImageLink\":\"https:\/\/photos.zillowstatic.com\/p_c\/ISzbrso7jduzha1000000000.jpg\",\"isPreforeclosureAuction\":false,\"homeStatusForHDP\":\"FOR_SALE\",\"priceForHDP\":318000,\"festimate\":306939,\"priceChange\":-5000,
```

But this return is a string, I literally load a page and return the content of the page

What I am doing is this, I know I am certainly wrong. I am testing everything on js, not really a JS guy

```
string_.indexOf(/^"yearBuilt\"$/)
```

Comment: Please post the code that you are trying and explain what results you got and what results are you expecting.

Comment: Your input string looks a lot like a fragment from JSON.  Are you trying to parse JSON content here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes but the response is a string, its a whole HTML page but I just want that specific data

Comment: just updated my post @palaѕн

Comment: Since it is JSON, put everything into JSON.parse("{"apiCache".....}") and it will convert it all into data.

Comment: the thing is I cannot directly parse it since it returns as a whole web page, I am using curl to get the page and feed it back to my ajax. @QuentinUK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want to get a year, you could use a RegEx, with [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), something like:

```
'\"yearBirthday\":1979'.match(/yearBirthday\":(\d{4})/)[1]
```

```js
console.log('\"yearBirthday\":1979'.match(/yearBirthday\":(\d{4})/)[1]);
```

Comment: I think I miss my point on the question. I want to find the "yearBirthday" first then get the value "1979". Its a bunch of string "its probably a html page" but returns string

Comment: I've updated my answer, it should do what you want now.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/DQG7WDn , I got this error with the answer provided. Did I miss something, as far as I know that the whole HTML page was converted into string, so you can imagine that this string consists of html tags, but I just want the script that below the page

Comment: When working with regular expressions, you need to be sure about the format of the string you're trying to match. That error implies the string is slightly different, but it should point you in the right direction :)

Comment: I will accept this answer. I am pretty sure that this works, but as what Luis told it might be my string format, but I want you to ask luis something where can I send you dm atleast a few mins

Answer (score 0):

You can use match and capture group

```js
let str = `"{\"VariantQuery{\\\"zpid\\\":28261252}\":{\"property\":{\"zpid\":28261252,\"streetAddress\":\"3415 Willow Ridge Dr\",\"zipcode\":\"77339\",\"city\":\"Humble\",\"state\":\"TX\",\"latitude\":30.058258,\"longitude\":-95.199617,\"price\":318000,\"dateSold\":1560543353000,\"datePriceChanged\":1584715800000,\"bathrooms\":5,\"bedrooms\":5,\"livingArea\":3777,\"yearBuilt\":1979,\"lotSize\":9539,\"homeType\":\"SINGLE_FAMILY\",\"homeStatus\":\"FOR_SALE\",\"photoCount\":67,\"imageLink\":\"https:\/\/photos.zillowstatic.com\/p_g\/ISzbrso7jduzha1000000000.jpg\",\"daysOnZillow\":247,\"isFeatured\":false,\"shouldHighlight\":false,\"brokerId\":16722,\"contactPhone\":\"\",\"zestimate\":306939,\"rentZestimate\":2500,\"listing_sub_type\":{\"is_FSBA\":true},\"priceReduction\":\"$5,000 (Mar 20)\",\"isUnmappable\":false,\"rentalPetsFlags\":64,\"mediumImageLink\":\"https:\/\/photos.zillowstatic.com\/p_c\/ISzbrso7jduzha1000000000.jpg\",\"isPreforeclosureAuction\":false,\"homeStatusForHDP\":\"FOR_SALE\",\"priceForHDP\":318000,\"festimate\":306939,\"priceChange\":-5000,\"isListingOwnedByCurrentSignedInAgent\":false,\"timeOnZillow\":1564615080000,\"isListingClaimedByCurrentSignedInUser\":false,\"hiResImageLink\":\"https:\/\/`

let yearBirthday = str.match(/"yearBuilt":(\d+)/)

console.log(yearBirthday[0])
console.log(yearBirthday[1])
```